# Writing to file in Applescript - not working

Tags: file, applescript

I've been trying to write to a file the results of an xmlhttp GET request. I have tried the code below:

```
set the_file to "/Users/xxxx/Documents/outputvals.txt" as file specification

set the_data to costItems

try
    open for access the_file with write permission
set eof of the_file to 0
write (the_data) to the_file starting at eof as list
close access the_file
end try
```

However it doesn't seem to write anything to the file. Ideally I want to write the xml 'costItems' to the end of a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you want to do anything with a file or folder, it must be a complete `alias` reference. Just change `as file specification` to `as POSIX file as alias` and that part will work!

Also, remove the `as list` and delete the line `set eof of the_file to 0`. Assuming the file already contains information, you're basically telling the script that the end of the file is the beginning of the file.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:** I don't know why your code isn't working properly (it does for me). Well, I guess you could try the following (kind of hacky, though, but oh well :P )

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set the_file to "/Users/xxxx/Documents/outputvals.txt" as POSIX file as alias
    on error --file doesn't exist yet, so create it
        set the_file to (make new document file at ("/Users/xxxx/Documents/" as POSIX file as alias) with properties {name:"outputvals", text:""}) 
        --Normally, when you're creating documents in this fashion, you would put the text you want in the document after the 'text' property, but for your sake I will use the alternative :)
    end try
end tell
set the_data to costItems
try
    open for access the_file with write permission
    write the_data to file the_file starting at eof
    close access the_file
on error --you never know when errors will crop up (when it comes to reading and writing files); better to be safe than sorry
    try
        close access the_file
    end try
end try
```

Comment: So ive got this at the moment:

set the_file to "/Users/Nick/Documents/outputvals.txt" as POSIX file as alias

set the_data to costItems

    try
 open for access the_file with write permission
 write (the_data) to the_file starting at eof
 close access the_file
    end try

But it still wont write to the file, and if i delete the file it wont remake it either, any suggestions?

Comment: Ive tried using that, but it still doesnt work, heres my code:

http://pastebin.com/UfmgZqqC

Comment: @user1045280 I took a look at the code; pretty good except for one thing--you forgot to convert `costItems` back to a string.

Comment: OK ive got it working using the original write to file I used before, however its adding 'listutxt' to the beginning each time and adding 'utxt' after each entry? Also, I want to add the date/time each time but when i use current time it just adds it to the end of the previous line rather than making it on a new line, how do I get it to be on a new line?